# How to split an html page to where clicking a link on the top half will open it on the bottom half, not affecting the top half at all

Tags: html

I want to have a top half with links and when clicked they will open various pages in the lower half of the screen and can be accessed by bootstrap tabs but i cant figure out how to split the screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you probably want to use an iframe element

Answer (score 0):

You can create two div part, one for the part where link is displayed and another for its content.

```
    <div id='navDiv'>Header</div>
    <div id='contentDiv'>some content</div>

    *In css-*
    #navDiv{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 10;
    }

    #contentDiv{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

You can see the example here - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/kLjIPwbLgDCVjpKE?open=lib%2Fscript.js